# Custom Triggers for Different Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Firstly excuse me for my lack of knowledge.
Let me explain my current situation.

I have 3 Tabs on one Spreadsheet:

- A master list
- Types of Stock
- Stock Requisition sheet

The master list simply gathers the information from the Stock Tab.
The Stock requisition gathers the information from Master list.

I currently have the following simple script that triggers based upon an edit.

```
function myFunction() {
  MailApp.sendEmail(
      "excessstock@greenlifepharma.co.uk",
      "Excess Stock - Someone Added Stock ",
      "Please see changes on main list of spreadsheet");
}
```

These are different triggers that i need...

1. A trigger for my function upon edit of the Stock sheet column C.
2. A different Trigger for when stock requisition sheet is edited.

Hope i explained well.

Comment: Did you read up on [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy to do what you require. Copy and paste the code below and set an `onEdit()` trigger.

**NOTE**: In the IF statment I have 'Stock' and 'Stock Requisition', these must be exact matches to the sheet names i.e. capitalisation and spacing.

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var getSheet = e.source.getSheetName();
  var getRange = e.range.getColumn();

     if(getSheet == "Stock" && getRange == 3 || getSheet == "Stock Requisition"){

        var stockEmail = "---------";
        var stockReqEmail = "----------";

         MailApp.sendEmail(
            (getSheet == "Stock") ? stockEmail : stockReqEmail ,
            "Excess Stock - Someone Added Stock ",
            "Please see changes on main list of spreadsheet");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works exactly how i wanted however... I would like to make just one change. I would like for the stock Req trigger to be sent to a different email address of my choice. Thanks

Comment: @RichardGreenLife See the updated code. Enter the emails in the vars.. If it's the Stock sheet it gets sent to stockEmail and if it's the Stock Requisition sheet it gets sent to stockReqEmail. Please accept my answer as correct by clicking the green tick.

Comment: Just a quick question. hope you dont mind. On the MailApp part at the bottom. What does the part (getSheet == "Stock") refer to. in particular "Stock"   I ask this because i have changed the name of the Sheet called stock and have changed the top part to match however not the bottom part? I am not currentley getting emails upon edit and i feel this has something to do with it.

Comment: `var getSheet = e.source.getSheetName();` This part of the code gets the name of the sheet that the user edited. The part "Stock" is the sheet name  (the name in the tab on Google Sheets". If you change the name of the sheet then you need to also change it in `if(getSheet == "Stock"` and `(getSheet == "Stock") ?` by replacing Stock with the new sheet name. NOTE: The name must be an exact match i.e. case and spelling also be careful of whitespace: "Stock " is not the same as "Stock" because of the space character.

Comment: Thanks for this James! is there a reason for the Mail only relating to the stock sheet and not the stock req sheet? or does this not make a difference.

Comment: You asked that if the stock sheet gets edited it gets sent to one email and if the stock req sheet gets edited it gets sent to a different email. This piece of logic handles that. If the stock sheet is edited the email is send to the email address in var stockEmail if not it gets sent to the address in var stockReqEmail